# Perl: Multiple lookbehind regex in a single regex expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl and regular expressions so was working on `lookbehind` expression using the below code:

```
my $string = "My hello 12 world 13";

say "$1 $2" if ($string =~ m!(?<=hello\s)(\d+)\s(?<=world\s)(\d+)!);
```

Now when I try to run the above code it prints nothing but if I remove one of the lookbehind expr. it works fine.

So, is it not possible to have more than one lookbehind in a single regex and if yes than what is the workaround.

Comment: could you show input and desired output of your logic?

Comment: @fxzuz: I just want `12,13` as output but I also want to know why my above regex is not working. It is just part of a learning exercise and I am aware that there are other ways to extract `12,13`.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex contains this part:

```
(\d+)\s(?<=world\s)
```

This reads as: "Capture a sequence of digits. Then match one space character. Then assert that the current position is preceded by the string `world` followed by a space."

So we are looking at this:

```
         \d+   \s
         world \s
My hello 12       world 13
```

`world` and `12` does not match ;-)

So why not use an ordinary regex in this case?

```
m/ hello \s (\d+) \s world \s (\d+) /x
```

Or use two regexes with look-behind?

```
$string =~ m / (?<=hello\s) (\d+) /x;
my $x = $1;
$string =~ m / (?<=world\s) (\d+) /x;
my $y = $1;
```

Look-arounds are mostly useful as a mind-mangling exercise, or to exclude parts of a string in a search and replace-operation. Assuming we want to correct `a owl` etc to `an owl`. We coud do that by

```
s/ \b a \s+ ([aeiou]) /an $1/x; # ugly
```

or with a look-ahead:

```
s/ \b a (?=\s*[aeiou])/an/x; # elegant
```

Whith normal pattern matching, the pattern can usually be expressed without look-arounds.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have more than one lookbehind in an expression.

The problem is: a look around assertion is not matching something of the text, so you have a "world" in your text, but you don't match it

You just check if there is "world" before the second series of digits ==> this is not true, so your regex fails.

You could do

```
(?<=hello\s)(\d+)\s\w+\s(?<=world\s)(\d+)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?323p3)

[regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is agood source of information about regexes, maybe their explanation of lookarounds helps you in understanding.